# Nodejs http server of electron app is not setting correct content-type header of local file if file has no extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I created a desktop application using electron and Nodejs. Here I am downloading some HTML, CSS and JS and other asset files like images, videos to render a web page locally. The files are being downloaded using window.fetch and saved locally. The downloaded and saved HTML file doesn't have file extension.

A Nodejs HTTP server is created to serve the file when required. The response from Nodejs server contains correct content-type header if the file has extension but when there is no extension, the response contains application/octet-stream as content-type.

So when the locally saved HTML file is requested from the NodeJS serve, instead of rendering/displaying the HTML file, a popup comes to save the file.
Tried to use [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) to detect the type of file and set the content-type in response but it is not working for HTML file.
If switched to chromeos app from Electron app then this is working fine.

Tried to use [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) to detect the type of file and set the content-type in response but it is not working for HTML file.

Below is the code for downloading the files. The url is the url of HTML file and resources like css, js, images etc.

```js
     download: {
        value: function(url, destination, settings = {}) {
            const fse = global.nodeRequire('fs-extra');
            const nodePath = global.nodeRequire('path');

            return this.fetch(url, settings).then(response => {

                if (!response.ok) {
                    return Promise.reject(new Error(response.code));
                }

                return fse.ensureDir(nodePath.dirname(destination))
                    .then(() => nodeWriteStream(destination, response));
            });
        }
    }
```

Below is the code for accessing the locally stored file using Nodejs server. Here I tried to use [file-type](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) to detect the type of file and set the content-type in response but it is not working for HTML file.

So first I read the file and checked if the file starting with  and if so then set the content-type header in response but I am looking for some better way.
Here ***path*** is the root path of HTTP server where all the downloaded files are being stored.

```js
const http = require('http');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');
const serveIndex = require('serve-index');
const finalhandler = require('finalhandler');
const httpShutdown = require('http-shutdown');

function startServer(path) {
    var self = this;
    this._startPromise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        const serve = serveStatic(path); // path is the document root of this http server
        const index = serveIndex(path, {'icons': true, view: 'details'}); // Serve directory indexes for path (with icons)

        const server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

            serve(req, res, function(err) {
               const done = finalhandler(req, res);

                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                } else {
                    index(req, res, done);
                }
            });
        });
        server.listen({port: self._port, host: 'localhost'}, function() {

            self._server = httpShutdown(server);
            this._startPromise = null;
            resolve('http://localhost:' + self._port);
        });
    });
    return this._startPromise;
}
```

Comment: Need some code to check what's the issue

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The file-type lib you tried to use is for binary-based file, not text file.

What you are looking for is a lib which can detect filetype by their signature or using other content detection technique.

I suggest you to have a look at the node module [mmmagic](https://github.com/mscdex/mmmagic), it do exactly what you want.